# What is the Japanese onomatopoeia for radio static?

Tags: english-to-japanese, onomatopoeia, sound-symbolism

Something like "Bzzz". I'm thinking it's either ブーン or ザーザー, but I can't find any source to really confirm it. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It will be most commonly ザー or ザーザー.

[This](https://www.gabastyle.com/english/naruhodo/naruhodo28/) explains the translation of ザー (though it's about TV) as *static* in English.

> 「テレビのザーっという音」って英語で？
>
> 日本語ではこの音のことをいろいろな言い方をしますが、英語では「雑音」や「静電気」を表わす“static”を使います。電話の雑音も同じ言い方です。